# Handling nulls on get calls in Vogels.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, vogels

I'm using Vogel.js to connect to Amazon DynamoDB. It's great, however one thing I'm struggling with is that a call such as

```
MyEntity.get({ my_key: keyValue }, callback);
```

will either return null if there is no results, or will return a wrapper object.

If I just want to read `MyEntity` as an object, it appears that in my callback I then have to do

```
const myEntityAsAnObject = queryResult.get();
```

however, this will throw if there was no results. So then I have to do some null checking before I do the get. Which I could use lodash or something for, but I'm wondering - is there a nicer way to do this? something like

```
MyEntity.getAsObject({ my_key: keyValue }, callback);
```

that will always return the unwrapped object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The least-inelegant thing I can think of is a higher order function wrapper:

```
function attrs(callback) {
  return function attrsInner(error, model) {
    callback(error, model && model.get())
  }
}

MyEntity.get({ my_key: keyValue }, attrs(callback));
```

You could also consider monkey patching the vogels model class prototype in a similar fashion, but I think that would violate the principle of least surprise for someone maintaining your code.